# I'm not able to expose a script from within a snap

Tags: snap

So I'm trying to learn how to create a snap package, and are using a simple python script as a base (https://gitlab.xirion.net/vroest/dice-roller/tree/master).
I have gotten snapcraft to work properly, and have installed the snap package but I'm not able to get the script to run from my terminal.

```
snap install --devmode --dangerous cli-diceroller_1.9_amd64.snap
```

I have followed the guide here: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-your-first-snap#3
Here is the yaml-file:

```
name: cli-diceroller
base: core18
version: '1.9'
summary: A python dice rolling application using standard dice notation
description: |
  Syntax is: roll <dice_code>
  Example: roll 2d8 + 6 + d8
  Instead of a dice code you can also put "stats" or "dir" for a stats roll or direction roll respectively.

grade: devel
confinement: devmode

apps:
  roll:
    command: bin/roll

parts:
  diceroller:
    plugin: python
    python-version: python3
    source: https://gitlab.xirion.net/vroest/dice-roller.git
```

when i run this command, the script works as normal

```
/snap/cli-diceroller/x1/bin/roll
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app name (`roll` in this case) is different from the snap name (`cli-diceroller`) the binary is installed as `<snap-name>.<app-name>` to prevent namespace clashes:

```
$ cli-diceroller.roll
Syntax is: roll <dice_code>
Example: roll 2d8 + 6 + d8
Instead of a dice code you can also put "stats" or "dir" for a stats roll or direction roll respectively
```

If you rename your part to `cli-diceroller`, the executable will be available under that name. (This is documented on the [snapcraft.yaml reference](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snapcraft-yaml-reference).)

Comment: ahh. i see. i missed that since it's not mentioned in the tutorials i found.
i'll make sure to check the reference next time i don't understand something!

Comment: I think that executable naming rule could be better explained, I'll report that to the documentation maintainers :)